# Angular equivalent of silverlight binding to an property of an element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, silverlight

In silverlight, if I have two xaml objects declared in the same user control, I can bind the property of one of the objects to a property of another object by using the "ElementName" binding option like so:

```
<Object1 x:Name="xObj1" Date="{Binding DateInViewModel}"/>
<Object2 Date="{Binding ProcessedDate, ElementName=xObj1}"/>
```

In this case, object 1 receives a date from the view model and has a property called "ProcessedDate", which contains a changed version of the input date.  Object 2 has a property called "Date" that is bound to the "ProcessedDate" of object 1.

How can I do something similar in Angular?

Comment: It'd be great if you could validate my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the very straightforward ng-attr directive. See [documentation](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/docs/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives_demo_-attribute-bindings)

In the following example, the div's `whatever` attribute will be bound to the input value ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ArnaudRinquin/4C5sB/)).

```
<input ng-model='foobar'>
<div ng-attr-whatever="{{foobar}}"></div>
```

Here is a more [complexe example](http://jsfiddle.net/ArnaudRinquin/BskAu/5/) using directives.

Comment: My understanding is that, the above only works if 'foobar' is a property in the controller?  I want to bind to a property being output by another element, without going through the controller.  With respect to your example, I would want to do something like this <div ng-attr-whatever="{{inputControlName.value}}"/>.  In the silverlight case, there is no need for a property to be declared in the view model for this to work.

Comment: The "ElementName" option in the binding is all you need to point the binding to an element, rather than to the datacontext (i.e. scope) as it is by default..

Comment: It's always better to have a controller ruling independent directives. However, controller is totally optional. See this [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ArnaudRinquin/4C5sB/1/)

Comment: I still do not understand how this would work when both objects are custom directives, not inputs or divs.  Let's say I have these two elements instead:<directiveOne stuff='{{myStuff}}'/><directiveTwo stuff='{{myStuff}}'/>  Does that work?  I'm not sure how to do this with a custom attribute rather than ng-model.

Comment: The use a controller and share values through custom directive isolated scopes (see [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive)). Seriously, controllers are important, don't try to avoid them. Update: yes that'd work, but remove the curly braces and use double binded isolated scope ([jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ArnaudRinquin/BskAu/5/) mixing everything).